# jquery function ajax is not returning data from webmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have this jquery function that I call from a DOM event:

```
function GetAdhesiveWeight(volatiles1, volatiles2, testedWeight) {

            var volatiles1 = $('#<% = FormView1.FindControl("textVolatiles1").ClientID %>').val()
            var volatiles2 = $('#<% = FormView1.FindControl("textVolatiles2").ClientID %>').val()

            var testedWeight = $('#<% = FormView1.FindControl("textTestedWt").ClientID %>').val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "NomexLine500A.aspx/CalcAdhesiveWeight",
                data: '{"dblVolatiles1":"' + volatiles1 + '", "dblVolatiles2":"' + volatiles2 + '", "dbTestedWeight":"' + testedWeight + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#<%=FormView1.FindControl("textPerVolatiles").ClientID %>').val(data.d)
                }

            });

        }
```

It gets called from this event:

```
$('#<% = FormView1.FindControl("textVolatiles2").ClientID %>').bind('change', function () {
            GetAdhesiveWeight();
        });
```

The event fires fine and goes into the GetAdhesiveWeight function fine.
A web method in my code behind file gets called from ajax:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function CalcAdhesiveWeight(ByVal dblVolatiles1 As Double, ByVal dblVolatiles2 As Double, ByVal dblTestedWeight As Double) As String


    Dim dblVolatiles As Double


    dblVolatiles = (((dblVolatiles1 - dblVolatiles2) * 2) * 1000)



    Return Format(dblTestedWeight - dblVolatiles, "#.00")

End Function
```

I am not making it into the VB function when i set breakpoints. I think there is something in the ajax that is wrong.

I tried to debug it with FireBug, but I am not too good with that tool yet. I am fairly new to jQuery so any feedback would be great.

Comment: What error do you see in the network console?

Comment: Please Check below link

[how-to-format-json-for-asp-net-webmethod-that-takes-class-parameter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023259/how-to-format-json-for-asp-net-webmethod-that-takes-class-parameter/21026621#21026621

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I got it to work by adding
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
to my ajax