# How to format JSON for asp.net webmethod that takes class parameter

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asmx, webmethod

I have the following webmethod on my asp.net code behind page:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool SaveFailureData(SimpleFailureData data)
{

}
```

SimpleFailureData is defined as the following:

```
public class SimpleFailureData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public double Adjustment { get; set; }
    public List<ShutdownData> ShutdownData { get; set; }
}

public class ShutdownData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool CausedShutdown { get; set; }
    public string ShutdownType { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to call this webmethod and format my data so that it is projected/parsed into that class correctly so I can use it. I tried sending a json string to the method, but my breakpoint inside the method was never hit (so I assume the method failed to call due to improper data format).

This is the JSON I tried sending and then calling the method:

```
json = JSON.stringify( {
    Comments: comments,
    Score: score,
    Adjustment: seAdjustmentValue,
    ShutdownData: breakdowns //this is an array of shutdown objects
});

PageMethods.SaveFailureData(json, function(data) {
    return;
});
```

But this failed to get inside my method. Any tips on what the JSON format should be so that is properly works for passing a class as a parameter?

Here is the JSON I attempted to send to the method:

```
{
"Comments":"",
"Score":66.66666666666667,
"Adjustment":0,
"ShutdownData":[{"Id":"401","CausedShutdown":true,"ShutdownType":"NORMAL"}]
}
```

Comment: can you please post the exact json sample..AFAIK..you have to catch the data in your webmethod in a string variable and then use JavaScriptDeserializer class in .Net to case the string to the class

Comment: @Arpit I added an example in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this

```
    public static bool SaveFailureData(string sampleFailure)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        SimpleFailureData sdata = s.Deserialize<SimpleFailureData>(sampleFailure);
        return true;
    }

    var json = {
                "Comments": "",
                "Score": 66.66666666666667,
                "Adjustment": 0,
                "ShutdownData": [{ "Id": "401", "CausedShutdown": true, "ShutdownType": "NORMAL"}]
            }

            var data = JSON.stringify(json);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Default.aspx/SaveFailureData',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: "{'sampleFailure' : '" + data + "'}",
               // data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });

        });
```

you will get the data in sdata object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did end up using the `PageMethods.SaveFailureData` way, but it still worked the same.

Comment: that's an intelligent solution

Answer (score 3):

Follow the Below step and you will get your required output

### **Ajax function Call**

```
function CallAjaxRequest() { 
    var Simplefailuredata = {};
    Simplefailuredata.Id = 1;
    Simplefailuredata.Comments = 'Comments-1';
    Simplefailuredata.Score = 500.25;
    Simplefailuredata.Adjustment = 700.25;
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData = new Array();
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData[0] = new Object({ Id: 2, Description: "Desc-1",  CausedShutdown: true, ShutdownType: "ShutdownType-1" });
    Simplefailuredata.ShutdownData[1] = new Object({ Id: 5, Description: "Desc-2", CausedShutdown: false, ShutdownType: "ShutdownType-2" });
    var object = JSON.stringify({ simplefailuredata: Simplefailuredata });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default2.aspx/GetResponse",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: object,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    });
}


<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
 <input type="button" id="btn"  value ="t" onclick="CallAjaxRequest();"   />
 </div>
</form>
```

### **Code Behind**

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetResponse(simplefailuredata simplefailuredata)
{
    return "";
}
}



public class simplefailuredata 
{ 
public int Id; 
public string Comments; 
public double Score; 
public double Adjustment; 
public List<shutdownData> ShutdownData; 
} 

public class shutdownData 
{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Description { get; set; } 
public bool CausedShutdown { get; set; }
public string ShutdownType { get; set; }
}
```